# RestEasy path solving

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I get something like this

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

public class xxx
{

  @GET
  @Path(value = "path1")
  public Response m1(@QueryParam(value = "a") String a)
  {
    ...
  }



  @GET
  @Path(value = "path2")
  public Response m2(@QueryParam(value = "b") String b)
  {
    ...
  }

}
```

With restEasy I get HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative every time when i try to get path1 or path2
For ex http://someip:8080/myserv/services/path1?a=asd

Here http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html_single/#Using_Path I read

> The @javax.ws.rs.Path annotation must exist on either the class and/or a resource method. If it exists on both the class and method, the relative path to the resource method is a concatenation of the class and method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `services` if it is not a part of your servlet mapping or path.

(Also more info about your path/servlet mapping will make us understand better)

EDIT:

So your project is deployed with myapp context name + you have services prefix + path defined in resource class.+ servlet mapping is /* so /myapp/services/path should work.

You can increase the logging level for resteasy classes to see what is wrong. or in debug mode you can see what path is requested in PathHelper.replaceEnclosedCurlyBraces

EDIT2:

If you are auto scanning, classes needs to be annotated with @Provider

Resteasy v1.2.1

```
@Provider
@Path("/")
public class xxx
{

  @GET
  @Path(value = "path1")
  public Response m1(@QueryParam(value = "a") String a)
  {
    ...
  }



  @GET
  @Path(value = "path2")
  public Response m2(@QueryParam(value = "b") String b)
  {
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I have resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix set to /services

Comment: and resteasy.scan set to true.
What more should I tell You?

Comment: 99.99% percent of the time, computers don't do mistakes :) So only way is  to debug and see what is wrong. One thing i don't see on your class is,  @Component annotation, have you annotated your resource class? Scan=true requires this annotation.

Comment: I have second class with only one method with @path annotation for class and it work fine, I dont have any @component annotation, I will check now

Comment: Sorry about @Component, my bad. I will update the original answer in a bit.

Comment: It should be @Resource. @Component also works if you are using spring

Comment: How this @resource annotation should look like to save current url: http://someip:8080/myserv/services/path1?a=asd ??

Comment: I dont know how my @Resource annotation should looks like

Comment: just annotate your class with @Resource. see above.

Comment: are you using this one javax.annotation.Resource , it has a default name empty string, you dont have to specify it.

Comment: yes , I'm using javax.annotation.Resource, will provide a log in few minutes

Comment: try @Provider as well, what version jdk resteasy you are using?

Comment: I should have asked that long ago. The one I am using is 2.0.3 so it may be different from the one you are using as the major release number changed, means big change from v1 to v2.

Comment: That's why I add link to documentation, prop you dont have any idea how to do that using 1.2.1? I have to use this ver

Comment: if you can create quick start project I can take look at it

Comment: I double check, and with @Provider and @Path("/") and it started to work with 1.2.1, thanks a lot!

Comment: good to hear. I will update the answer than if anyone reads this later.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the value= in your path notation? I'm not 100% on what the value= is used for since I'm quite new to JAX-RS but maybe try out just doing:

```
@GET  
@Path("path1")  
public Response m1(@QueryParam(value = "a") String a)  
{  
  ...  
}
```

Comment: I will try, by I think this is ok

Comment: If this doesn't work could you verify that your servlet mapping in the web.xml file is <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>

Comment: Removing the `value=` has no effect, it is the default.

Comment: as Elazar touched but didn't explain, @Path("xxx") is syntactic sugar for @Path(value="xxx")